# I can prove that $f(U(p;\epsilon))\subset U(f(p);\epsilon)$ but I cannot prove that $f(U(p;\epsilon))\supset U(f(p);\epsilon)$. ($f$ is isometry)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I am reading "Set Theory and General Topology" (in Japanese) by Yohei Komori.

> Let $(X,d_X)$ be a metric space.
> $U(p;\epsilon):=\{x\in X\mid d(x,p)<\epsilon\}$.

> Let $(X,d_X),(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces.
> Let $f$ be a mapping from $(X,d_X)$ to $(Y,d_Y)$ such that $d_X(p,q)=d_Y(f(p),f(q))$ for all $p,q\in X$.

The author wrote $f(U(p;\epsilon))=U(f(p);\epsilon)$ holds for any $p\in X$ and any $\epsilon>0$.

I can prove that $f(U(p;\epsilon))\subset U(f(p);\epsilon)$ but I cannot prove that $f(U(p;\epsilon))\supset U(f(p);\epsilon)$.

If $f$ is surjective, then I can prove that $f(U(p;\epsilon))\supset U(f(p);\epsilon)$ as follows:

> Let $q'\in U(f(p);\epsilon)$.
> Then, there exists $q\in X$ such that $f(q)=q'.$
> Assume that $d_X(q,p)\geq\epsilon$.
> Then $d_Y(f(q),f(p))=d_Y(q',f(p))\geq\epsilon$.
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $d_X(q,p)<\epsilon$.
> So, $q\in U(p;\epsilon)$.
> So, $q'\in f(U(p;\epsilon))$.

But I cannot prove that $f(U(p;\epsilon))\supset U(f(p);\epsilon)$ if $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: If $f$ is not surjective, then it's really easy to find counter-examples.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $f(x) = (x,0)$. Then $f$ is an isometry in the sense that $d_{\Bbb R}(p,q) = d_{\Bbb R^2}(f(p),f(q))$ for all $p,q$, but $f(U_{\Bbb R}(0;1)) \neq U_{\Bbb R^2}(0;1)$.

Comment: Didier, Thank you very much for your answer.